# Using BigInteger to get byte arrays from giving Binary String, returned byte array dosen's contain 0 value byte

Tags: java

I am trying to convert 160 length binary string into 20 bytes. I am using BigInteger to get a byte array. It only returns 14 bytes, I need 20 bytes.

Here is my code:

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000010000010100001011111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
byte[] newData = b.toByteArray();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20 - newData.length; i++) {
    output.write((byte) 0x00);
}
output.write(newData);
newData = output.toByteArray();
```

Comment: What is the point of doing it this way, you can make a byte array normally, and despite what you think I am sure bigInteger is doing the conversion correctly

Comment: did you even read the documentation on `toByteArray()`? "The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger". It trims the leading zeroes, after all it expects to be dealing with numbers.

Comment: Why the heck are you trying to fit 160 bits into 8 bytes?

Comment: To make it work the way you're expecting it to, you'll need to force the 1st bit (on the left) to be "1", and then convert it back to 0 in your byte array.

Comment: @iCode4Food From my point of view this is the wrong way to go about it, since he is manually creating it, also not everyone reads the java documentation before they code, this guy is clearly a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You might already know this but to make a 20 byte array you do this:

```
byte [] arr = new byte[20];
```

you can then put the elements you want in manually.

The reason that you are not getting the desired result is because BigInteger is trimming the leading zeroes so maybe this is not a good tool for what you want to achieve.

You may also you a string to create a byte array.

```
String s = "9B7D2C34A3623432DF30641E6CECF6F";    
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(s.toCharArray());
```

To me this seems like the best way to create your array. **By the way this isn't the hex representation of your string, you can do that yourself**